# Office-addin, Elevated permission error on saving custom properties

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

While saving and deleted custom properties getting below error

**Error: Elevated permission is required to call the method: 'item.saveCustomProperties'.**

I have read permissions for the mail.

**Could anyone please through a light on what is Elevated permissions?**

**Appreciate if redirected to document link.**

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available soon. Depending on the release channel a customer is on, getting an updated build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response.