# Pinned Outlook web addin: ItemChanged event stops arriving

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have a user for whom our pinned addin stops receiving ItemChanged event after a while (Outlook desktop only). We can always reproduce this situation in Outlook and there are no errors in the JavaScript log.

What could be happening? Outlook stops firing events? Office.js loosing our event handler? How can we debug this? We can attach to the process using the Edge Dev tool.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest posting this to https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues .

Comment: @Alexey, does your add-in contain a <Select> dropdown? We have an issue here : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1100. Could this be related?

Comment: This could be it. The event stops arriving always after filling out a form with a bunch of selectors. But this happens for a few users only. What is different about their setup?

Comment: On the other hand for this user this issue happens only in Outlook (desktop), not when run in IE/Edge/Chrome. Any idea what exactly is breaking? Event handlers get reset?

Comment: Yes, the event handlers are getting reset. We have observed this issue only in Desktop Outlook clients that use Edge as the underlying browser to launch web add-ins. If the underlying browser being used by Desktop Outlook is IE, this issue does not occur.

Comment: You can keep an eye on the GitHub post for progress on this issue.

Comment: Is it possible to switch Outlook to using IE instead of Edge? We need a workaround for our user. Thank you.

Comment: If the user removed Edge this way (https://www.wintips.org/how-to-completely-remove-edge-browser-from-windows-10/) would Outlook switch to using IE 11?

Comment: I cannot recommend the removal of Edge using the link you provided. We have documentation here about the underlying used for Outlook/Office add-ins depending on your Windows + Office combination: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins. If your customer has another machine with an older version of Windows 10, that will be a better way to try out your add-in and avoid this issue. Will that help?

Comment: One temporary workaround, just for validation purposes, is to remove the event handler (removeHandlerAsync) and re-add it (addHandlerAsync) whenever you get a change event on a <Select> element. This depends on the complexity of your add-in.

Comment: Planning to try the suggested workaround ...

Comment: Confirming, the suggested workaround helped!