# Outlook add-in elevated permission is required to call the method: 'mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync'

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Some executions of my side-loaded Outlook add-in report this permissions exception in my remote logger when they're run:

```
Error Elevated permission is required to call the method: 'mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync'. 
    https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:187671 G
    https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:204853 We
    https://[mydomain]/AppRead/Home/Functions.js:22:9 Anonymous function
    https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js:46:22370 Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.onReadyInternal
    https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js:46:22842 Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.onReady
    https://[mydomain]/AppRead/Home/Functions.js:17:5 functionName
    https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:156870 Anonymous function
```

The add-in manifest specifies the following permissions:

```
<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
</Rule>
```

Based on the stack traces I have, it's always outlook-win32-16.02.js and Edge browser, so it seems to be isolated to recent-ish Outlook. I've logged a decent number of these, though it's not happened frequently enough that any customer has reported it.

It definitely seems similar to this question [Elevated permission is required to call the method: 'mailbox.getUserIdentityToken'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389935/elevated-permission-is-required-to-call-the-method-mailbox-getuseridentitytoke), but I'm not using a timer control and this is executing in the onReady(), so Office.js should be loaded.

Have I missed a new security change that's specific to that platform? Or is my understanding of either Office.onReady() or ReadWriteMailbox permissions flawed?

Comment: We are trying to track down some issues related to this. Any information you have that may help us repro the issue would be appreciated. What type of Add-in is this? (mail compose, mail read, appointment organizer etc.) Is it Pinnable? Version of Outlook this started happening in? If you have a local repro, perhaps any steps leading up to the repro that may be notable?

Comment: It's a mail read add-in with no taskbar that takes the execute function action. I do not yet have a local repro, I'm only seeing it in the field atm, but I am working on that.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Do you have any logging to determine the version of Outlook in which this issue is occurring?